# Android RelativeLayout class cast exception

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, classcastexception

Hi guys I have a class that `extends RelativeLayout` and I want to inflate an xml file with `RelativeLayout` as the parent viewgroup and then assign it to the variable.

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {
....
}
```

Within activity `onCreate()` method:

MyLayout layout;

```
layout = (MyLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_page_one, null);
```

This is causing a class cast exception. Perhaps someone can shed some light.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.example.test.MyLayout
```

Comment: In your layout_page_one.xml, do you specify a RelativeLayout or your MyLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can typecast sub Class to Super class but not Super class to sub calss so In your `R.layout.layout_page_one.xml` Xml file Instead of definig `RelativeLayout` define MyLayout
thyen it will work..